# Knockout.js: How to use the dropdown selected item and optionsValue parameter?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to have editable drowpdowns inside a list.
In one of those dropdowns, everytime the value is changed I need to perform an update on another value (outside of that part of the code). To perform that update, I need to use the values inside the row object (the 'item' in code placed below) and values inside the selected dropdown object.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: quantityList, as: 'item' }">
<tr data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <td>
        <select data-bind="options: $root.groupList,
            optionsText: 'description',
            optionsValue: 'groupId',
            value: groupId,
            optionsCaption: ''" style="width: 99%; "></select>
    </td>
    <td>

        <select data-bind="enable: options: $root.productList,
            optionsText: 'description',
            optionsValue: 'productId',
            value: productId,
            optionsCaption: '',
            event: { change: function() { $root.updateGrade(item, $index(), productId) } }" style="width: 99%; "></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My issue is, if I don't use the parameter "optionsValue: 'productId'", when the page is loaded the dropdown apears empty. But the full dropdown object is passed in my function called when the value is changed (parameter 'productId').
On other side, if I use the parameter "optionsValue: 'productId'", the dropdowns are correctly filled with the values selected before and stored into DB. But in the 'updateGrade' function, the parameter 'productId' only have a number,correspondent to the id.

Is there any way to use in the function called at the change event, the full selected dropdown item and mantaining the parameter 'optionsValue' in dropdown definiton?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown should definitely not be empty when you don't supply the `optionsValue` option. You could either bind to the `change` event like you're doing now, or alternatively you could subscribe to the observable that holds the value of the select.

See my Fiddle here where this all works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/jtbumgc3/